# How can I deploy my nodejs app into openshift without using github?

Tags: node.js, openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools

I have built a nodejs app and now I want to deploy it into openshift.
I don't want to use github because I should create private repository which I cannot.
Also I cannot use 'rhc' since I am new user.
Is there any way to do that?
I cannot find any tutorial about that.

Comment: You could always push to a git repo just while you deploy, then delete the repo right after...very unlikely anyone would find the repo in the amount of time it would take you to pull it onto your deployed machine...just my $0.02cents as I run into this with "coding exams", and as long as we don't keep the data living on github, a quick push and pull and then delete is pretty low key...

Answer (score 4):

For OpenShift 3, you can use a binary input source build.

First create a binary input build.

```
oc new-build --name myapp --strategy=source --binary --image-stream=nodejs:latest
```

Now start a new build and upload source code from the current directory.

```
oc start-build myapp --from-dir=.
```

Once the build has completed, deploy the image created by the build.

```
oc new-app myapp
```

You can then expose the service.

```
oc expose svc/myapp
```

Every time you want to make a change, you will need to run the same `oc start-build` command in the directory where your source code is.

Comment: So I don't need to use git?

Comment: Using that method no, you can just push from your local file system. So you can use a different version control system, local Git but without using a hosted Git repository as a master, or you can not use a version control system at all.

Comment: I've tried this but when I run the first command I get:error: User "airp320" cannot create imagestreams in project "default"
    error: User "airp320" cannot create buildconfigs in project "default"

Comment: Create a new project. You should not be trying to do anything in the ``default`` project. That project is for services related to the running of OpenShift itself. That project is only usable by an admin and even then they should not really be running additional stuff in it. So run ``oc new-project somename`` to create a new project and work in that. If you already have a project, use ``oc project somename`` to switch to it.

Comment: I've done everything as expected but when I open the url tab I get 'Application is not available'. The app is working fun in local environment.(it's a really simple helloworld app with express).

Comment: Are you using OpenShift Online or your own OpenShift installation? They are having some issues at the moment with route setup in Online environments. Consider trying with Minishift on your own local computer.

Comment: I am using openshift online. Why should I run my app locally? I want my app to be seen by others.

Comment: The point of running it on a local MiniShift instance is simply to validate that everything is installing and working fine. This will confirm that you are currently affected by the OpenShift Online routing issues. MiniShift is also great for doing local development before you make your changes public.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any other code repo you are using? SVN? If SVN, you can use pipelines with Jenkins.

If not, put the nodejs app in a docker container and push it to the docker hub.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anybody to suggest this so I will do - you can equally well deploy code from [gitlab](http://gitlab.com), [pagure](http://pagure.io), [bigbucket](http://bitbucket.org), or any other git hosting service.

In fact you can even run your own git server inside OpenShift.

```
oc create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openshift/origin/master/examples/gitserver/gitserver-persistent.yaml
oc env dc/git -p ALLOW_ANON_GIT_PULL=false
oc policy add-role-to-user edit -z git
oc get route # to see your git server URL
```

Now you should be able to push/pull from that server using your OpenShift username and token (also any other users you add to the project). From `buildconfigs` and other `pods` you can also use simply `git` as the hostname of your git server, because this should resolve to the IP of the `service` with the same name (again only within the same OpenShift project).

Read the template YAML (the URL after `oc create`) for more options you can use like `REQUIRE_GIT_AUTH`.

Of course it is good to keep a git mirror/backup somewhere else as with any other git service.

HTH

P.S. Forgot to say, you need to install an OpenShift v3 cluster by yourself or subscribe to [OpenShift Online](https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html) (which unfortunately may take awhile ATM).